# How do you reset access permission for Apple Configurator 2 on a Mac mini?

Tags: applications, permission

I am trying to install my app as an .ipa file on an iPhone device attached to my Mac mini. I used Apple Configurator 2 menu Actions > Add > Apps..., then selected the button **Choose from my Mac...**. The first time I browsed to my desktop, selected the .ipa file, then clicked **Add**.

I was asked to provide permission to access the drive and I clicked the wrong button, denying permission. It provided an error message and canceled the operation. Now every time I try to add the file, I get this error message.

An unexpected error has occurred with "iPhone name".
The operation couldn't be completed. Operation not permitted. [NSPOSIXDomainError - 0x1 (1)]

The only option is **Stop**, which causes the operation to be canceled. Since the Apple Configurator 2 app does not ask for permission again, I can't approve.

Is there a way to reset permissions for this app without affecting the other apps and settings on this Mac?

Comment: An overnight update to version 2.11.1 and the problem has disappeared. My app could be selected and transferred to the iPhone device. No permissions were requested but no errors occurred. As we say in the software development business, "Fixed by magic". Although that leaves the original question unanswered. Was there a way to reset the permission that was originally chosen incorrectly?